# MiKTeX won't connect to server

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I discovered that my MiKTeX installation (on a Windows 10 computer) is unable to connect to the package and/or update servers after installation. What's more, when I attempt to update or add a package, the list of "Remote Package Repositories" shown to me is empty.

Downloading the packages I want into a local repository and installing them from there is also impossible, since running miktexsetup also results in a "Couldn't connect to server" error.

My first suspicion was that this was some kind of issue with my Firewall. However, after I had added exceptions for "miktex-console.exe" to the Firewall I still had the same problem.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: installing from a local repository should work. What happens exactly if  you go to miktex console -> settings ->tab general and click on change?

Comment: Are the servers available from your ISP (it may be a kind of firewall _on their side_ for some reasons)? Try to `ping` them

Comment: I eventually fixed this by removing MiKTeX entirely and doing a clean install, but the reasons for this remain a mystery.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by reinstalling MiKTeX mentioned in comment.